# Changing navigationOptions of screen in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am trying to force the header of the route in StackNavigator to become visible / show up / render only when the component (assigned as a screen to this route) has received props in componentWillReceiveProps (because at that moment the ListView, that the screen is solely comprised of, appears). How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this.props.navigation.setParams` to update `navigation.state.params`, and use it in your **navigationOptions function**. Seems that's the only way.

Comment: The problem here is that the property that makes the header invisible is a part of navigationConfig, not navigationOptions, which is also a part of navigationConfig. And the headerVisible property does not exist, according to the official docs, and it did not work, wherever I put it.

Comment: Did you config `headerMode: 'none'` in navigationConfig? That was disabled header. I think you can config with `navigationOptions: { header: { visible: false }}`, and then enable in your screen component. I just created a demo at https://snack.expo.io/rJ0UWOdSW. The header of screen is not shown, when you click the button, it shows.

Comment: Great solution! But it seems that is not for my case, since I need to call the onPress function from componenWillReceiveProps and it does not work this way. The component just keeps loading infinitely.